# prag_match_all How to count multiple occurrences

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have the following sample:

```
$text="
the line
the line
the line
also remember this line
the line
also remember this line
";
```

I need to know how many times `the line` is repeated when it's found.

UPD:
Ok. Let's say I don't need to count them. I need the expression that matches that sample. Keeping in mind that I want to remember `the line`. There are several occurrences of that line in different numbers in different rows.

UPD2:

`$text=" the line 150. the line the line 150.";
preg_match_all("/ (the line) [0-9]+\./i",$text,$matches);
print_r($matches);`

I want the matches be `the line 150.` and `the line the line 150.`

The expression matches only the first part of the sentence, but not the second. That's what my problem is.

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research ?

Comment: So where are we with this question? Did any of the answers below solved your problem ?

Comment: Your code from update 2 works fine for me! http://3v4l.org/oLjQF Please specify your problem more!

Comment: I need ` the line 150.` And ` the line the line 150.` to be returned. This is the closest expression I could use.

Comment: Please add your expected output into your question!

Comment: do you want matches all lines, beginning with 'the line'?

Answer (score 3):

This is the perfect use-case for [`substr_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php), just use it like this:

```
echo substr_count($text, "the line");
```

output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 2):

`preg_match_all` is one way to go but remember that using regex has some penalty performance. So with that in mind try to use the `string` functions whenever possible.

If you only want to know the number of occurrences of a sub-string then `substr_count` might be easier to use.

```
$needle = 'the line';
$count = substr_count($text, $needle);

echo $count;
```

And if you want to make it case insensitive just lowercase both the needle and the haystack.

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php) you can pass an array to hold all matches for the string. If you grab count from this array you'll find exactly what you need:

```
<?php

$text="
the line
the line
the line
also remember this line
the line
also remember this line
";
preg_match_all('/the line/', $text, $matches);

echo count($matches[0]);
```